# req.body is empty prototype in onRequest firebase cloud functions (With multer)

Tags: google-cloud-functions, webhooks, sendgrid

In my cloud function:

```
const app = express();
app.use(multer().array());
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("hit", req.body.from);
  console.log("hit", req.body.from);
  return res.sendStatus(200);
});

const emailInboundWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(app);

module.exports = {
  emailInboundWebhook
}
```

I get this in logs:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "emailInboundWebhook"
>  hit undefined
>  hit undefined
i  functions: Finished "emailInboundWebhook" in ~1s
```

But when the same endpoint served as an express app(outside cloud functions):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({foo: "Bar"});
})
app.use(multer().array());
app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("hit",req.body.to);
  console.log("hit",req.body.from);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(80, () => {
  console.log("App listening on 80");
})
```

Gives this:

```
hit a@some-email-inbound.some.url
hit Rahul Priyadarsi <myemailid@gmail.com>
```

The two results are for same email sent and these functions are fired as sendgrid webhooks which send `multipart/form-data` POST requests that contain details of the email sent to `a@some-email-inbound.some.url` from `myemailid@gmail.com`

I have no idea as to why the two results are different(I am testing them via ngrok and since the console log lines run, clearly the function is hit).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Take a look in this issue: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/572

Switch from Multer to Busboy, is also a good option.

One thing: In this situation use https.Request (from cloud-functions) instead of Request from express.